# python : how to copy files from two different locations?

Tags: python-2.7, copy

I'm trying to share a bunch of scripts that exist in a share folder. However 5 files will need to be copied to each users local folder for local preference settings.

I have 2 source folders and 2 destination folders. How do copy each file to it's respective destination in python?

Thanks,

Ricky

Comment: Copying files from two different locations is the same as copying one file from one location, except you do it twice, supplying a different directory name each time.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, so simple I wonder why I didn't just try that.